# A user in an Owner's group cannot Add Users, only Groups

Tags: permissions

I would really appreciate someone's help if possible. I have set up a site with a series of sub sites, which I thought was working fine until I asked someone I had set up as an Owner of a sub site to do a test and try to add a new user. Although they have full control they only get the option to add a new group. They are in the Members group of the parent site and the permissions have been broken. I wondered if this had anything to do with it? I'm clutching at straws a bit here ... Any ideas, would be really helpful ... Thanks

Comment: I created an "Core Team" Group and added some users to it. Then I set this "Core Team" Group as the Owner to other groups in my share point. However the users from "Core Team" are not able to invite other users to the groups. As a matter of fact, they are not able to see these groups. The Core Team are not site owners and don't have Full Control. They are not supposed to be Full Owners. Their responsibility is to manage access to the groups assigned to them
Kindly assist

Answer (score 6):

Exactly, as in the previous answers, groups are managed only through their owners, not through the site owners. This was weird for me at first, too.

However, to work around that: Add the site owners as the owners for the newly created groups!

Answer (score 3):

The above sugestions would work but would create a dangerous security vulnerability since now any member of the group would be able to add new members.

What you want to do is to create a new group that contains the various adminstrators of your site and asign this group as the owner of the group. This way any administrator can add new members but only administrators have this ability.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to add new users to the group is generally controlled by "Group Settings":
[image]

As a site collection admin, select the group and select Settings > Group Settings to access it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Group Owner settigns]

You need to change the **Owner** Option of the **Group Owner**.(In your case the SharePoint group to which you want to give access to add user to this group).

It doesnt matter if they have a full rights or not on this site they can still add users to this group if they are owner of this group.